# Calculation with clicking on a button within JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

i am trying to create such calculation within a texArea which i calculate in one class, and i pass this onto a different class to perform the next calculation with only clicking buttons. So if i click on 'm10py' , whatever i have in the TextArea will be decreased by 0.10. I tried everything but it just doesnt seem to work. It doesnt throw any errors but the total in the TextArea stays still.
My main class where it performs the basic calculation.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    double frontM = 9.50;
    double middleM = 7.30;
    double backM = 6.70;
    double vipM = 12.90;

    //double total1 = Double.parseDouble(output.getText());


    if (frontR.isSelected() && e.getSource() == calculate) {

        double total = Integer.parseInt(frontT.getText()) * frontM;

        output.setText(pounds.format(total));

    } else if (middleR.isSelected() && e.getSource() == calculate) {

        double total = Integer.parseInt(middleT.getText()) * middleM;

        String total2 = String.valueOf(total);

        output.setText(total2);

    } else if (backR.isSelected() && e.getSource() == calculate) {

        double total = Integer.parseInt(backT.getText()) * backM;
        output.setText(pounds.format(total));

    } else if (vipR.isSelected() && e.getSource() == calculate) {

        double total = Integer.parseInt(vipT.getText()) * vipM;
        output.setText(pounds.format(total));

    } else if (e.getSource() == cancel) {

        frontT.setText("1");
        middleT.setText("1");
        backT.setText("1");
        vipT.setText("1");
        output.setText("");

    }
    if (e.getSource() == payment) {
        Payment paymentJ = new Payment();
        paymentJ.output.setText(output.getText());

    }

}
```

Second class which the calculation is passed on to a different textArea. I didnt do it for every button because i couldnt manage to the calculation.. ;

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Main main = new Main();
    //  double totalR = Double.parseDouble(output.getText());

    String cost = main.output.getText();
    double cost2 = Double.parseDouble(cost);
    double total;
    total = cost2;

    double m10py = 0.10;
    double m20py = 0.20;
    double m50py = 0.50;
    double m1p = 1.00;
    double m2p = 2.00;
    double m5p = 5.00;
    double m10po = 10.00;
    double m20po = 20.00;

    if (e.getSource() == m10p) {

        total = total - m10py;

        String total2 = String.valueOf(total);

        output.setText(total2);

    }

}
```

I'm fairly new to this so please dont go have a go at me. I just need to know what is wrong with this. Thanks

Comment: It would help greatly if you created and posted a valid [mcve], a small but complete program that only has necessary code to demonstrate your problem, that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification, as this would help us to fully understand what you might be doing wrong. Note that this is code posted as code-formatted text and not as a link to an off-site resource.

Comment: I certainly stated what the problem is, and have linked the necessary code below which is what really needed to perform the calculation within 'actionPerformed' method.  Any other coding will be rather unnecessary which are just properties of the frame etc...  I dont understand the down vote and having no replies regarding to such easy problem for you guys out there?

Comment: You'll have a much better experience here if you read the [mcve] link to see why it's important, why it helps us understand your problem much better, why it will help us provide a decent and quick answer. For example if you had read the link before replying you'd know that our being able to compile and run your code, our being able to make adjustments to runnable code, gives us much greater ability to see any and all problems involved. Again, we're not asking to see the entire program, just a small runnable example. Yes, this means that we're asking for extra work from you .... (to be cont)

Comment: ... but please understand that you're asking for free work from volunteers, so is this really asking too much from you? Is this really our being unreasonable? I can guarantee that if you do this, if you post this code here (and again not in a link), and you do a decent job, the down-vote will be changed into an up-vote, and you'll likely get an answer quickly. Your call.

Comment: Also, and most importantly -- where in your code is the error occurring? Can you tell us? I certainly can't tell you just by looking at it, but with a [mcve] I will have a much greater chance of doing just this.

Comment: Note that this: `Main main = new Main();` doesn't look right. Not sure what you're trying to do here, but double check your rationale.

Comment: Ah, I see, you're trying to get info from it: `String cost = main.output.getText();`, but likely the Main object that you created just here and placed into the main variable is **not** the same Main as the one that is probably being displayed. Debug this -- find out what value is held in output when you try to get its text by printing it out to the console. I will bet you that it's whatever default value that it is given or null.

Comment: e.g., after this line: `String cost = main.output.getText();`, do `System.out.println("value of cost: " + cost);` and see what you get. If I'm right, I still can't tell you how to fix this other than to make sure that you get the value from the output field in the **displayed** Main instance, not in one created within the ActionListener. Again how to get this reference is currently unknown to me and to all looking at this question. If you want more help, *again*, please improve it.

Comment: I appreciate for the advice and will apply this on future posts.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I **do** know is that you've got a serious reference problem going on. For example in your first posted actionPerformed method:

```
if (e.getSource() == payment) {
    Payment paymentJ = new Payment(); // ***** line 1 ****
    paymentJ.output.setText(output.getText());  // ***** line 2 ****
}
```

On line 1 above you create a **new** Payment object, called paymentJ, and on line 2 you change its state, by calling `output.setText(...)`. I'm guessing that output is some text component, and you're trying to change the text that it displays, but here's the problem -- while paymentJ refers to a Payment object, it's not the Payment object that is being displayed, which is a completely distinct separate object, and changing the state of the non-displayed one created here by trying to change the text it displays, will have no effect on the output text component in the actualy displayed Payment object.

Similarly in your second posted actionPerformed method:

```
Main main = new Main();  
//  double totalR = Double.parseDouble(output.getText());

String cost = main.output.getText(); // ***** line 1 ****
double cost2 = Double.parseDouble(cost); // ***** line 2 ****
```

On line 1 above you create a **new** Main object, called cost, and on line 2 you query its state, by calling `output.getText()`. But again the Main instance created here is not the same Main object that is being displayed, and again this means that you have at least two (or *more*) Main objects, only one of which is being displayed, and the data that your extracting from the one created locally here will not reflect the changes made to the one that's displayed.  You can test this by placing a println after you extract the text, for example:

```
Main main = new Main();  
//  double totalR = Double.parseDouble(output.getText());

String cost = main.output.getText(); 
System.out.println("cost is currently: " + cost); // ***** add this ****
double cost2 = Double.parseDouble(cost);
```

I will bet that you'll see a default value that is held by the text component returned, and not a value that was entered by the user or was displaying in the currently visualized Main GUI.

What to do?

- Well for one, you could make the output fields **static**. That would be a quick and easy solution, but unfortunately it would be quick, easy and very very wrong, since this would break OOPs principles, making your code very difficult to test, enhance and inherit.
- Better would be to pass references in where needed, for instance pass a reference to the *displayed* Payment object into the object that has that first actionPerformed method, and then call the appropriate methods on that object, and likewise pass a valid reference to the *displayed* Main object into the object whose code is displayed in your lower code snippet. This will allow you to query and modify the states of valid displayed objects. How to do this? I can't tell you specifically how to do this without a better and working code example from you (as per my comments). Generally, you could pass references around using constructor and setter method parameters.
- Best would be to make your code more M-V-C or Model-View-Controller like, but this may be overkill for this program and may be beyond your current level of coding at this time.

For more help, for better help, please improve your question.

---

Based on your new code,

- your Payment class should extend JDialog, not JFrame since a GUI should only have one main window
- You will want to pass Main into Payment via `Payment paymenetJ = new Payment(this);`
- You will need to change the Payment constructor to accept this: `public Payment(Main main)`
- And inside the constructor use the parameter to set a field: `this.main = main;`
- Then use this main field instead of creating a new Main object.

Comment: I will repost this problem with a more specified question and link my code as you said, because it seems like my question wasnt clear enough.

Comment: i reposted my question with pasting the whole program which might give you what the problem is. any help will be appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165324/displaying-double-in-a-different-class-and-calculating-by-clicking-on-buttons