# Displaying Double in a different class and calculating by clicking on buttons

Tags: java

I am trying to create such calculation that outputs to my main Frame in a TextArea, and I pass this onto a different class/frame to perform the next calculation with only clicking buttons.

So if I click on 'm10py' in payment class, whatever I have in the TextArea will be decreased by 0.10. I tried everything but it just doesn't seem to work. It doesn't throw any errors but the total in the TextArea stays still.

My main class where it performs the basic calculation:

```
package coursework_resit;
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JLabel head = new JLabel("Cinema Ticket");
    JLabel front = new JLabel("Front Stalls (£9.50)");
    JLabel middle = new JLabel("Middle Stalls (£7.30)");
    JLabel back = new JLabel("Back Stalls (£6.70)");
    JLabel vip = new JLabel("VIP (£12.90)");
    JLabel outputL = new JLabel("Total Amount :");

    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    JButton payment = new JButton("Pay");
    JButton calculate = new JButton("Calculate");

    JTextField frontT = new JTextField(6);
    JTextField middleT = new JTextField(6);
    JTextField backT = new JTextField(6);
    JTextField vipT = new JTextField(6);

    JTextArea output = new JTextArea();

    ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton frontR = new JRadioButton("", false);
    JRadioButton middleR = new JRadioButton("", false);
    JRadioButton backR = new JRadioButton("", false);
    JRadioButton vipR = new JRadioButton("", false);

    DecimalFormat pounds = new DecimalFormat("£#,##0.00");

    double total2;

    public Main() {

        super("Cinema Ticket");
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 350);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        buttonGroup.add(frontR);
        buttonGroup.add(middleR);
        buttonGroup.add(backR);
        buttonGroup.add(vipR);

        add(frontR);
        frontR.setBounds(60, 110, 22, 13);
        frontR.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        add(middleR);
        middleR.setBounds(270, 110, 22, 13);
        middleR.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        add(backR);
        backR.setBounds(270, 200, 22, 13);
        backR.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        add(vipR);
        vipR.setBounds(60, 200, 22, 13);
        vipR.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        frontR.addActionListener(this);
        middleR.addActionListener(this);
        backR.addActionListener(this);
        vipR.addActionListener(this);

        head.setBounds(280, 10, 300, 40);
        getContentPane().add(head);
        head.setFont(new Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", Font.BOLD, 30));
        head.setForeground(Color.white);

        front.setBounds(90, 70, 200, 50);
        getContentPane().add(front);
        front.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        front.setForeground(Color.white);

        frontT.setBounds(110, 110, 50, 25);
        getContentPane().add(frontT);
        frontT.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        frontT.setText("1");

        middle.setBounds(300, 70, 200, 50);
        getContentPane().add(middle);
        middle.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        middle.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        middleT.setBounds(320, 110, 50, 25);
        getContentPane().add(middleT);
        middleT.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        middleT.setText("1");

        getContentPane().add(back);
        back.setBounds(300, 150, 200, 80);
        back.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        back.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        backT.setBounds(320, 205, 50, 25);
        getContentPane().add(backT);
        backT.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        backT.setText("1");

        vip.setBounds(90, 150, 200, 80);
        getContentPane().add(vip);
        vip.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        vip.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        vipT.setBounds(110, 205, 50, 25);
        getContentPane().add(vipT);
        vipT.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        vipT.setText("1");

        outputL.setBounds(570, 55, 200, 80);
        getContentPane().add(outputL);
        outputL.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        outputL.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        output.setBounds(590, 110, 100, 25);
        getContentPane().add(output);
        output.setEditable(false);
        output.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));

        payment.setBounds(580, 210, 120, 40);
        getContentPane().add(payment);
        payment.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 16));
        payment.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        payment.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        payment.addActionListener(this);

        calculate.setBounds(580, 160, 120, 40);
        getContentPane().add(calculate);
        calculate.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 16));
        calculate.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        calculate.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        calculate.addActionListener(this);

        cancel.setBounds(580, 260, 120, 40);
        getContentPane().add(cancel);
        cancel.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 16));
        cancel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        cancel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        cancel.addActionListener(this);

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.gray);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        double frontM = 9.50;
        double middleM = 7.30;
        double backM = 6.70;
        double vipM = 12.90;

        //double total1 = Double.parseDouble(output.getText());


        if (frontR.isSelected() && e.getSource() == calculate) {

            double total = Integer.parseInt(frontT.getText()) * frontM;

            output.setText(pounds.format(total));

        } else if (middleR.isSelected() && e.getSource() == calculate) {

            double total = Integer.parseInt(middleT.getText()) * middleM;

            String total2 = String.valueOf(total);

            output.setText(total2);

        } else if (backR.isSelected() && e.getSource() == calculate) {

            double total = Integer.parseInt(backT.getText()) * backM;
            output.setText(pounds.format(total));

        } else if (vipR.isSelected() && e.getSource() == calculate) {

            double total = Integer.parseInt(vipT.getText()) * vipM;
            output.setText(pounds.format(total));

        } else if (e.getSource() == cancel) {

            frontT.setText("1");
            middleT.setText("1");
            backT.setText("1");
            vipT.setText("1");
            output.setText("");

        }
        if (e.getSource() == payment) {
            Payment paymentJ = new Payment();
            paymentJ.output.setText(output.getText());

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main main = new Main();
    }
}
```

My 'Payment' class where the user clicks on a button and and whatever the textArea contains, will decrease by the amount of the button that's clicked.

```
package coursework_resit;
public class Payment extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    JButton change = new JButton("Collect change");
    JButton dispense = new JButton("Dispense Ticket");

    JButton m10p = new JButton("10p");
    JButton m20p = new JButton("20p");
    JButton m50p = new JButton("50p");
    JButton m1 = new JButton("£1");
    JButton m2 = new JButton("£2");
    JButton m5 = new JButton("£5");
    JButton m10 = new JButton("£10");
    JButton m20 = new JButton("£20");

    JTextArea output = new JTextArea();
    JLabel totalA = new JLabel("Total amount needed :");

    DecimalFormat pounds = new DecimalFormat("£#,##0.00");

    public Payment() {

        super("Payment");
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.gray);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        totalA.setBounds(50, 340, 250, 50);
        getContentPane().add(totalA);
        totalA.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        totalA.setForeground(Color.white);

        output.setBounds(50, 390, 280, 30);
        getContentPane().add(output);
        output.setEditable(false);
        output.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));

        dispense.setBounds(50, 450, 200, 50);
        getContentPane().add(dispense);
        dispense.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        dispense.setForeground(Color.white);
        dispense.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        cancel.setBounds(50, 510, 100, 50);
        getContentPane().add(cancel);
        cancel.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        cancel.setForeground(Color.white);
        cancel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        m10p.setBounds(50, 70, 100, 50);
        getContentPane().add(m10p);
        m10p.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        m10p.setForeground(Color.white);
        m10p.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        m20p.setBounds(180, 70, 100, 50);
        getContentPane().add(m20p);
        m20p.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        m20p.setForeground(Color.white);
        m20p.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        m50p.setBounds(50, 140, 100, 50);
        getContentPane().add(m50p);
        m50p.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        m50p.setForeground(Color.white);
        m50p.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        m1.setBounds(180, 140, 100, 50);
        getContentPane().add(m1);
        m1.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        m1.setForeground(Color.white);
        m1.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        m2.setBounds(50, 210, 100, 50);
        getContentPane().add(m2);
        m2.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        m2.setForeground(Color.white);
        m2.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        m5.setBounds(180, 210, 100, 50);
        getContentPane().add(m5);
        m5.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        m5.setForeground(Color.white);
        m5.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        m10.setBounds(50, 280, 100, 50);
        getContentPane().add(m10);
        m10.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        m10.setForeground(Color.white);
        m10.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        m20.setBounds(180, 280, 100, 50);
        getContentPane().add(m20);
        m20.setFont(new Font("Cambria", Font.BOLD, 20));
        m20.setForeground(Color.white);
        m20.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    }

    @Override

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Main main = new Main();
        //  double totalR = Double.parseDouble(output.getText());

        String cost = main.output.getText();
        double cost2 = Double.parseDouble(cost);
        double total;
        total = cost2;

        double m10py = 0.10;
        double m20py = 0.20;
        double m50py = 0.50;
        double m1p = 1.00;
        double m2p = 2.00;
        double m5p = 5.00;
        double m10po = 10.00;
        double m20po = 20.00;

        if (e.getSource() == m10p) {

            total = total - m10py;

            String total2 = String.valueOf(total);

            output.setText(total2);

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Payment();
    }
}
```

The only part thats giving me headaches are in the actionPerformed method in Payment class to be able to decrease the amount thats in textArea by clicking the buttons.

```
    Main main = new Main();
    //  double totalR = Double.parseDouble(output.getText());

    String cost = main.output.getText();
    double cost2 = Double.parseDouble(cost);
    double total;
    total = cost2;

    double m10py = 0.10;
    double m20py = 0.20;
    double m50py = 0.50;
    double m1p = 1.00;
    double m2p = 2.00;
    double m5p = 5.00;
    double m10po = 10.00;
    double m20po = 20.00;

    if (e.getSource() == m10p) {

        total = total - m10py;

        String total2 = String.valueOf(total);

        output.setText(total2);

    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't post a duplicate question but rather should improve your original question

Comment: Posted the entire code for you to run the program and see where the problem is. I did improved the question by splitting the whole code and the actual code where the problem is occuring for me.

Comment: Please check out the  [help] section. You should edit and improve the original question so that it is answerable,  not ask a new question.